# Why are all Xaml UI elements private in Visual Studio Blend - how can i change the acess modifier

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-code, uwp, uwp-xaml

I used Visual Studio Blend to create text fields in xaml. Now, I want to access them in code but whwen i type. Textfieldname.Text it says that it can't access it because it is private. When I change the auto-generated xaml code so these elements are public it fails to compile. How can I access such text fields in code / make them public? [image: Here you can see the errors.]

I tried everything, but in the inspector tab etc. there are no options for the access modifiers. (but I am an absolute noob in visual studio)

Comment: If you have given control x:Name, it will generate private filed in the .i.cs file automatically. and you could access it in current cs file. but it could not access with current page instance in other class, it's by design, I tried to update it to public, it does not throw error in my side, but the i.cs file will re-generate when clean current project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit the auto-generated file as it will be overwritten when you recompile.

If you want to make an auto-generated field available outside the class, you could use the [x:FieldModifier attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to change its access modifier in the XAML markup:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tb" x:FieldModifier="public" Text="..." />
```